# installation error of Anaconda 3: Filenotfound

Tags: installation, anaconda

While installation of Anaconda 3 on Windows 8 it shows this error message and then complete the installation:

> Filenotfound error: [winerror 2] The system cannot file the specified

After installation completed, there is no application.

Comment: Does that typo ('their') come directly from Windows? :p

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you are asking @Nibor

Comment: @j7ee Nibor message means that you previously had a poorly spelled and poorly formatted post. But the culprit was the edit from Gholamali-Irani. I have now fixed it.

Comment: @GholamaliIrani Thank you for capitalizing, but it's better to fix spelling mistakes instead.